# Why can't I open a file from a variable made from several concatenating strings in Python?

Tags: python

So I wrote this code

```
spec = raw_input("Enter the specimen number: ")
naorimp = raw_input("Native or Implant (N/I)? ")
trial = raw_input("Trial number: ")
typana = raw_input("What do you want to analyze (contact area[CA]/contact pressure[CP])? ")

try :
    if typana.lower() == "cp" :
        naorimp = naorimp.upper()
        TSfilnm = 'pressure'+spec+naorimp.upper()+trial+'.txt'
    else :
        naorimp = naorimp.upper()
        TSfilnm = 'area'+spec+naorimp+trial+'.txt'
    TSfile = open(TSfilnm, 'r')
    myofilnm = 'accelerometer'+spec+naorim.upper()+trial+'.txt'
    print myofilnm
    myofile = open(myofilnm, 'r')
except :
    print "File could not be found."
    print "Please re-run the program."
    exit()

print "OK"
```

I want to open a file based on user's input and several parameters (specimen no., native or implant, trial no., and type of analysis.) The file is already in the same folder as the python file code. But when I run the program I always end up with except statements (File could not be found. Please re-run the program). I have double-checked the real file name and the string inside the `TSfilnm` variable, and they are the same. However, the `TSfile` could not be executed.

P.S. The file name in my folder is: pressure3N1.txt, area3N1.txt, accelerometer3N1.txt

Comment: Are you sure that message "File could not be found. Please re-run the program" means that file not found? In fact it means that you have an exception, but you need to check the reason of this exception.

Comment: Also you can use `os.path.isfile(TSfilnm)` to check before opening that this file exists. Do it just to recognize the reason of the problem.

Comment: It turned out that i miss a 'p' in the variable name in certain line. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `p` in the variable name in this line

```
myofilnm = 'accelerometer'+spec+naorim.upper()+trial+'.txt'
```

should be

```
myofilnm = 'accelerometer'+spec+naorimp.upper()+trial+'.txt'
```

---

Also don't use 'except' alone during development, it will only hide errors like in this case. It's better to do something like.

```
import sys

try:
    #Your_code_here
except:
     print sys.exc_info()[1]
     #Any other code you wanna run
```

Comment: The way you have structured the code is not right. The try except block should only be around the part where you open the file. Otherwise, any error in the try block will cause you to think the file doesn't exist, when in reality the error is something else, like a variable name mistake.

Comment: You should also not use just `except:` as that will catch `KeyboardInterrupt`. Use `except Exception:`.

Comment: Yeah, the ideal is to have a `except Exception:` for any expected error, but it's also useful to have a general one at the end to catch any unexpected ones. My favorite is `except:    subprocess.Popen(['open', 'http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+'+str(sys.exc_info()[1])])`

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I did not expect that I would get the answer as quick like this. Big thanks also for the tips of the correct usage try and except. I will keep it in my mind, so I will not make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: @arnold, glad we could help, please set your question as answered so it can be closed